# a Mapping problem

Tags: real-analysis, functions

let $f$:**R**->**N** such that given any $x_1$,$x_2$ belong to **R** such that $x_1 < x_2$ then there exists a $x_3$ belongs to $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_3)> max(f(x_1),f(x_2))$. How many such mappings are possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\aleph_0^\aleph$ such mappings. The upper bound is trivial. For the lower bound, pick any function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(\pm \frac{p}{q}) = q$.

Comment: Please let me know in wordings as i am not able to follow the notation.

Comment: what is $\aleph_0$ ?

Comment: Aleph-null (i.e. countable infinity).  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Comment: @Rajesh D: I believe that Yuval means that the cardinality of the set of such functions ("how many" there are) is equal to the cardinality of the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, because the map can send the irrationals anywhere in the examples given, and the irrationals have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: the answer is cool! So the cardinality of the set of mappings is even greater than that of Real numbers ?(please let me know whether i got it  correct.

Comment: @Rajesh: That is correct.

Comment: I think your exponent should be c, the power of the continuum.  Aleph without a subscript is unclear.